# Key "name" for array with keys "1, 2" does not exist in GirManageParcsBundle:Parcs:manage.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, dql

I have this **request** in SQL:

```
SELECT count(distinct b.id), count(distinct e.id) FROM building, ensembles e, `parcs` p WHERE p.id = "1" AND e.parcs_id = p.id AND e.id = b.ensembles_id
```

This how I use this request in my **Symfony project**, in a controller `ManageController.php` :

```
class ManageController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $parc = $em->getRepository('GirDatabaseBundle:Parcs');
        $ensemble = $em->getRepository('GirDatabaseBundle:Ensembles');
        $building = $em->getRepository('GirDatabaseBundle:Buildings');

        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT p.name, count(distinct b.id), count(distinct e.id)
             FROM GirDatabaseBundle:Buildings b, GirDatabaseBundle:Ensembles e, GirDatabaseBundle:Parcs p
             WHERE p.id in (:id)
             AND e.parcs = p.id
             AND e.id = b.ensembles
             GROUP BY p.id')
        ->setParameter('id', '1');

        $parc = $query->getResult();

        return $this->render('GirManageParcsBundle:Parcs:manage.html.twig', array('parc' => $parc ));
    }
```

But, when I lauched my html.twig page `manage.html.twig`, I have this **error**:
**Key "name" for array with keys "1, 2" does not exist in GirGestionPatrimoinesBundle:Parcs:manage.html.twig at line 35**

So, here's the **code** for my twig:

```
{# CONTENT #}
<div class="panel-body">
    <p class="text-justify">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h4><u>Situation actuelle</u></h4>
                <p>
                    <h5>PARCS</h5>
                        {% for parcs in parc %}
                            <h4> {{ parcs.name}} </h4>
                         {% endfor %}
                </p>
         </div>
      </p>
```

I think, I don't use the good way to display the data like I want. Do you know it works ? And I would like to **display** the **name of my parc** and **his number of ensembles and buildings** that belong to him.

This is the Parcs class/entity code:
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * Parcs
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="parcs")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
   class Parcs
   {
     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

     /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

     /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Parcs
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->nom = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

This is the Ensembles class/entity code:

```
 /**
 * Ensembles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ensembles")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Ensembles
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="referenceClient", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
 */
private $referenceclient;

 /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

 /**
 * Set referenceclient
 *
 * @param string $referenceclient
 * @return Ensembles
 */
public function setReferenceclient($referenceclient)
{
    $this->referenceclient = $referenceclient;

    return $this;
}

 /**
 * Get referenceclient
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReferenceclient()
{
    return $this->referenceclient;
}

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Parcs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $parcs;

 /**
 * Set parcs
 *
 * @param \Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Parcs $parcs
 * @return Ensembles
 */
public function setParcs(\Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Parcs $parcs)
{
    $this->parcs = $parcs;

    return $this;
}

 /**
 * Get parcs
 *
 * @return \Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Parcs 
 */
public function getParcs()
{
    return $this->parcs
```

And this the last one, the buildings class/entity code:

```
class Batiments
{
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="referenceBatiment", type="string", length=150, nullable=false)
 */
private $referencebatiment;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Ensembles")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $ensembles;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set referencebatiment
 *
 * @param string $referencebatiment
 * @return Batiments
 */
public function setReferencebatiment($referencebatiment)
{
    $this->referencebatiment = $referencebatiment;

    return $this;
}

 /**
 * Get referencebatiment
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getReferencebatiment()
{
    return $this->referencebatiment;
}

 /**
 * Set ensembles
 *
 * @param \Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Ensembles $ensembles
 * @return Batiments
 */
public function setEnsembles(\Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Ensembles $ensembles)
{
    $this->ensembles = $ensembles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get ensembles
 *
 * @return \Gir\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Ensembles 
 */
public function getEnsembles()
{
    return $this->ensembles;
}
```

To answer to riska's comment:

For `{{ dump(parc) }}`, it returns me:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'bcnt' => string '307' (length=3)
      'ecnt' => string '104' (length=3)
```

and for `{{ dump(parcs) }}`, I have:

```
array (size=2)
  'bcnt' => string '307' (length=3)
  'ecnt' => string '104' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to alias the columns:

```
SELECT count(distinct b.id) AS bcnt, count(distinct e.id) AS ecnt
...
```

Now, you should be able to access to these variables:

```
{% for parcs in parc %}
    <h4> {{ parcs.bcnt }} </h4>
    <h4> {{ parcs.ecnt }} </h4>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: if I do like you propose me, I Have this error: "Key "bcnt" for array with keys "0" does not exist in .twig line 35." I don't think it's the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, that is weird. Try using var_dump in twig to get a better view for that data in parc and parcs:
{{ dump(parc) }}
{{ dump(parcs) }}

Comment: According to your update (and the twig documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) the solution I wrote should work. Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: yes I have cleared the cache. And, I just have seen that I have made a typo mistake. So it returns me the good result. Sorry, really... Now I would like to make the name of the parcs, and then the number of ensembles and buildings that belong to him. An idea how can I make it with twig?

Comment: Group by names in the query, put the group condition into the select (e.g. SELECT e.name AS name, ... GROUP BY e.name). Then you can access to the names in twig as you can access to the sums.

Comment: thank you a lot. I add my request with the GROUP BY argument in the updated code. But for now, I display one parc with his number of ensembles and number of buildings. In fact, I need to display all parcs with their owns number of ensembles and building in a table. I'm still looking how to do like that.

Comment: Then, you should remove that WHERE condition which filters your parcs to only one (as only one has that specified id).

Comment: I don't think I have to remove the WHERE condition. I Think I have to change the line where there is `->setparameter`no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66041/discussion-between-riska-and-julien).

Answer (score 4):

To avoid this error, be sure the variable you use in Twig are defined and not null :

```
{# CONTENT #}
<div class="panel-body">
    <p class="text-justify">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h4><u>Situation actuelle</u></h4>
                <p>
                    <h5>PARCS</h5>
                        {% for parc in parcs %}
                            {% if parc.name is defined and parc.name is not null %}
                            <h4> {{ parcs.name}} </h4>
                            {% else %}
                            <h4> Parc without name</h4>
                            {% endif %}
                         {% endfor %}
                </p>
         </div>
      </p>
```

BTW, you have a typo in your for loop, look at the code above.

Comment: sorry for the typo, I try your code. And my error is corrected. But, it does not display the data I want. It displays nothing by the way. I would like to display the number of buildings and ensembles belong to a parc, and display the name of the parc of course. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: For this you'll have to show us your class and/or classType, to see the relations between your entities.

Comment: Look at riska answer for the ensembles and buildings ;)